# Absolute positioned input field in Chrome

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I wanted to create a search form in my navigation bar which will expand on focus.

But somehow, the field gets focused even if I'm not clicking into the field.

Here is a demo: http://gaming-corp.de/

If you try to click on the white content area right under the search button on the top, it will focus it anyway. This only occurs in chrome.

Does anybody know what could cause this and how to fix it?

Thank you

EDIT:

Here is the code:

```
form#search {
    position: relative;
}

form#search input {
    width: 0;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 0px 0 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent url(../images/search.png) no-repeat 10px center;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    transition: all .6s;
    font-size: 12px;
}

form#search input:focus {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #666;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Link to random page? Mmh. Better post the code here.

Comment: It's fine for me, try to disable your chrome extensions for testing

Comment: Seems like there is something to do with the `position:absolute`

Comment: edited. just calm down I wanted to give you the example page. As you can see there is no adverts or something so why should I trick you on my page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but it seems to be caused by the "clearfix" code:

```
.container:after, .row:after {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  content: ".";
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
```

Since neither `.container` nor `.row` need to be cleared like that, I'd suggest you just remove that code.

Comment: thats it! - just added a visibility:hidden;